# The functional $F(f)= f(c)$ for $f\in C[a,b]$ is not continuous in $L^2$.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to find an example to show that it is not countinuous but I do not get anything. Any hint?

Note: $c\in[a,b]$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Better: isn't continuous in $C[a,b]$ with the $L^2$ norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: There exist elements $f\in L^2$ whose norm is $1$ but whose value at $c$ is as large as you wish.

Comment: Oh, I get what you say. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $a<c<b$. Let $f_n(x)=n(c+\frac 1 n-x)$ for $c \leq x \leq c+\frac  1 n$, $f_n(x)=n(x-c+\frac 1 n)$ for $c-\frac 1 n \leq x \leq c$ and $f_n(x)=0$ for $|x-c| >\frac 1 n$. Then $f_n \to 0$ in $L^{2}$ but $f_n(c)=1$ for all $n$. I leave the cases $c=a$ and $c=b$ to you.

Comment: Thank you very much.